# How to get checkbox value in a Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a checkbox in my form and I want to save its value into the database. When I check it, its value will be 1 and when I uncheck it then it's value will be 0. However, in the controller, I am getting `NULL` all the time. But why? Is it possible to solve without `jQuery`?

**Blade/View**

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.categories.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="category_is_menu"
                 value="{{ old('category_is_menu', isset($category) ? 'checked' : '') }}"/>
       </label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $category = new Category();
    $category->category_is_menu = $request->category_is_menu;

    return $category;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's giving me `NULL` for `category_is_menu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use the hidden input trick as mentioned in the other answers or just check if the input was passed at all. If it was passed at all it was checked, if its not there it was not checked:

```
$category->category_is_menu = $request->has('category_is_menu');
```

If it was checked you get true, 1, if it wasn't checked you get false, 0.

Answer (score 7):

Add a hidden input with the negative value just before the checkbox input (with the same value in the name attribute)

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="category_is_menu" value="0"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category_is_menu" value="1" {{ old('category_is_menu', isset($category) ? 'checked' : '') }}/>
</div>
```

The value in the checkbox input needs to be always 1.

A checkbox input in not sent in the request when it's unchecked, in that case the hidden input will be sent with the value 0.
When the Checkox is checked, it will overwrite the value to 1.