# Laravel update multiple records by using checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

I have checkbox for all customers in blade.And i want to when i click  here i change status.Now when i click checkbox it do all records status to 0 and new clicked statuses to 1.All old datas to 0.I dont want this.How i fix it.
It is controller sider

```
  $clients = Client::all();
      foreach ($clients as $client)
      {
          $client->is_slide_content = $request->has('is_slide_content.' .$client->id)? 1:0;
          $client->save();
      }
```

```
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="is_slide_content[{{ $cs->id }}]" class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>{{trans('back.add')}}</label>

                                                </td>
```

Comment: Do you want to update specific client status or all client status?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood what your issue is correctly.

When the data about the clients is being loaded their status (i.e. 'is_slide_content') is not taken into consideration thus all checkboxes are unticked. If you don't want the old values to change you should tell Blade that the ckeckbox should be checked by default by doing something like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="is_slide_content[{{ $cs->id }}]" class="checkbox" {{ $cs->is_slide_content == 1 ? 'checked' : '') }}>`

Please note that you may need to modify the code a bit but the general idea is the same.

Also this is a related question and you may find something useful:
[How to get checkbox value in a Laravel controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535668/how-to-get-checkbox-value-in-a-laravel-controller)