# How to save checkbox in Laravel when using RequestAll operations?

Tags: php, laravel

I update my data using the request operation (except some fields):

```
\App\Models\Customers::where('id', $id)->update($request->except(['_token', '_method']));
```

And this works great, except for checkboxs. The activeness of the customer is not saved correctly. It's always *false*.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" @checked(old('active', $customer->active))>
```

I know that checkboxs values returns either `on` or `off` and we can change it by using `value="1"`, however, implementing this change, will always put the value as `true` in DB.

I also know that I can use something like:

```
$data = $request->except(['_token', '_method']);
$data['active'] = $request->boolean('active');

\App\Models\Customers::where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

However this creates additional code and isn't pretty.

So, is there any better way to save checkbox input automatically? Doesn't Customers Model allow to create a function / determine that if the column active is filled in a request, to automatically convert it's value to a boolean?

Comment: You need like a setter/getter on your model. I can help you if you show what $request->active looks like when on and off

Comment: The trick in this answer will likely solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59535737/3965631, or you could use the `merge` method of the Request object, something like `Customer::where('id', $id)->update($request->merge(['active', (bool)$request->input('active', false)])->except(['_token', '_method']));`; Checkboxes do not send `off` if they are unchecked, so `(bool)$request->input('active', false)` will be `true` if checked ('on' is "truthy"), or `false` if unchecked. (Side note, you should be importing your Model, and it should be Singular, so `Customer`, not `\App\Models\Customers`)

Comment: @nikistag I can't see how setter/getter will help me with my problem? I'm talking about the save operation.

Comment: @TimLewis not a fan of that solution, however, I think I've found a temporary solution, by using middlewares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**...kind of.

I decided to create a middleware that will convert to boolean the value passed. There is no problem if the column `active` does not exists in the table you're currently storing / updating, as it won't be set in the `$fillable` property of the model.

```
// Your web.php routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'rectify_active'], function()
{   
    // Your controllers
});

// Middleware
class RectifyActive
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->merge(['active' => $request->boolean('active')]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works! I think you could probably make it more dynamic, with some properties in your Model, supplying a Model to this Middleware, then `foreach($model->checkboxProps as $property) { $request->merge([$property => $request->boolean($property)]); });`. Also, if you're using `$guarded` instead of `$fillable`, you might have issues with it as written .